# Ventrilo hook read in Flash ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hook

I would like to play a flash animation when someone talks in the VoIP program Ventrilo.

I have a simple animation setup within Adobe Flash and I would like to somehow trigger it when a specific person talks "keys-up" in Ventrilo.

I know the G15 keyboard can access Ventrilo remotely and display who is talking in real time so I think it should be possible to use this event to trigger a movie clip play command if I knew how to access it. I have looked for example code but can't find any.

I know this is probably a highly complex task but I'm sure there is a genius on Stackoverflow how knows how to do it or could at least set me on the right path.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not going to be an easy task and is going to require writing a C/C++ ANE.

You can use Windows API hooking to intercept calls from Ventrilo.

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/387670-api-hooking/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed

You would need to write an ANE to use this inside your AIR app.

http://www.flexjunk.com/2011/11/30/developing-an-air-native-extension-for-osx-and-windows-in-c/